# Which definition of discrete valuation should I choose?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

In page 3 of Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory", there is a notion called discrete valuation ring as follows:
[image]

But about discrete valuation, I have found two different definitions.

One is from Singh's "Basic Commutative Algebra", which is as follows:

[image]

The other one is from Atiyah's "An Introduction to Commutative Algebra", which is as follows:

[image]

For Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory", which definition should I choose?

Comment: Choose the one you like and is best for your work.

Comment: Let me make a slightly off-topic comment that I have made on MSE many times: if a book or paper has several authors, you should *not* choose a subset of those authors to refer to the work. (In this example, the book is by Atiyah _and_ Macdonald.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that Atiyah requires a discrete valuation to be surjective, but any non-surjective discrete valuation $v$ (as per Singh) can be made surjective: its image is $m\Bbb Z$ for some natural $m$, so we can define a new valuation $v'$ by $v'= \frac{1}{m}v$.